# Aks spot instance priority[

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a cluster with an on-demand nodepool and spot instance nodepool. I want to give spot instnace the highest priority of pods to be assigned and once its terminated only all pods should get assigned into my on-demand nodepool.
I know spot instance has a default taint and labels . what are ways to implement this change.

Answer (score 0):

To allow the pods to be scheduled on spot instances, you would need to set the needed tolerations in the pod manifest.

To make the pods "prefer" to be scheduled on spot instances, you can use node affinity, specifically "preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution".

Both tolerations and affinity are [documented here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node).